ASP.NET Core 8.0 web app deployment via https://freeasphosting.net
I'm trying to deploy website made using ASP.NET Core 8.0. I created a fresh ASP.NET Core Web Api project via VS, published and then uploaded it to https://freeasphosting.net/ and I'm getting this error:

HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime Common
solutions to this issue: The specified version of
Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
Troubleshooting steps: Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages Attach a
debugger to the application process and inspect

What's the problem? I'm following YouTube tutorials and they also not helping.

The error suggests the hoster or at least the settings you used on the hosted site don't support .NET 8. You'll have to check their docs or contact support to find out how to create a site with .NET 8. That's not a setting you can control from code or your project

It's quite possible the hoster hasn't bothered upgrading. The huge number of irrelevant ads suggests that hoster doesn't really bother. Hosters make money by selling hosting plans, not by serving ads. You should think very, very hard if you really want to deal with them. You can deploy to Azure or AWS using a free tier instead

Any reason to assume they support .Net 8.0? The website landing page says "Our ASP.NET Hosting service includes Free ASP.NET Core Hosting with MS SQL database support, .NET 7, .NET 6.0, .NET Core 3.1, .NET Framework 4.8".

Do they support .net 8? Please confirm with them first. From error message, it seems that .net 8 hasn't been setup on the server. If they don't offer it, you may take a look at Asphostportal, I'm using these guys, pretty cheap.


The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.

The error is clear, the hosting server doesn't install in the .NET 8 runtime and Hosting Bundle.

From freeasphosting website, we can see at present they are not supported hosting .NET 8 application.
So, you can contact the freeasphosting, and suggest them to add .NET 8 supported or you can host the application on another server, such as Azure App Service.
Besides, you can also consider downgrade the application to .NET 7 (refer to this article: Migrate from ASP.NET Core in .NET 7 to .NET 8), then host on freeasphosting.
